# Python subprocess stdin pipe

Tags: python, subprocess

Hello i have such problem. I need to login via subprocess. So i want to create a input pipe and write login and password to them.So i try to do something like this:

```
sp = subprocess.Popen([cmd],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
i, o = sp.communicate()
```

After first string i have such error `tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device`. And i have None value of `o`. How can i write smth to pipe in this case. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're not providing anything for `stderr`: `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

Answer (score 1):

From [`subprocess.communicate(input)` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> The optional input argument should be data to be sent to the child
>   process
>   ...
>   Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to
>   create the Popen object with stdin=PIPE. Similarly, to get anything
>   other than None in the result tuple, you need to give stdout=PIPE
>   and/or stderr=PIPE too.

i.e., to pass input to the subprocess, specify `input` parameter; to get a non-`None` `o` value, you must specify `stderr=PIPE`.

In many case password prompt and password itself are not written to/read from a pipe but directly to/from terminal i.e., you might need a pseudo-tty to pass the password unless the command allows to set an option to accept password via stdin. You could use [`pexpect`](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/) to interact with a child process using `pty`. See the first reason in  [Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)